# need help in sending email with attachment in Symbian

Tags: email, symbian, attachment

I am working with an app, in which I have to send e-mail with an attachment of an image.
And I have no idea about this thing.
working on Carbide.c++ (Symbian)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your [later question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990784/not-able-to-get-the-type-of-messagetype-in-email-app-of-symbian-3rd) I think you have already found pointers for proceeding. For reference to other people who may be looking for the same information, the [RSendAs API](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Sending_Emails_with_RSendAs) is probably the easiest solution.