# Not able to get the type of MessageType in email app of symbian 3rd

Tags: symbian, email, s60

I want to develpoe an app which sends email from IMAP4 settings of the phone.
And I am following this perticular wiki.

```
RSendAs send;
User::LeaveIfError(send.Connect());
CleanupClosePushL(send);

     RSendAsMessage sendMsg;
sendMsg.CreateL(send,**KUidMsgTypeSMTP** );
CleanupClosePushL(sendMsg);
sendMsg.SetSubjectL(_L("Incident Capture."));
sendMsg.AddRecipientL(_L("abc@xyz.com"),RSendAsMessage::ESendAsRecipientTo);
sendMsg.SetBodyTextL(_L("Image Attached"));

TRequestStatus status;
//add attachment
sendMsg.AddAttachment(_L("C:\\Data\\Images\\hhj.jpg"),status);
User::WaitForRequest(status);

sendMsg.SendMessageAndCloseL();
CleanupStack::Pop();
CleanupStack::PopAndDestroy();
```

Now I want KUidMsgtypeSMTP Uid. I am not getting how to use this thing.
How do I get the value of this constant.
when I used random Hex value 0x040, it gave me System Error (-1) at run time.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `#include <miutset.h>` system header as it contains

```
const TUid KUidMsgTypeSMTP                      = {0x10001028}; // 268439592
```